# Best apparel management sytem or inventory software system

Tags: windows, inventory

We are looking for an apparel management system or inventory system which satisfies the following:

- 10000+ inventory items
- 2000+ transactions per day
- Sale order and invoice management
- Customisable to suit the business process
- All tables import / export
- Debtors and creditors can be pushed to Reckon
- Report options (paper report, analysis, pivot, view, chart, inquiry)
- Large amount of screen data, simplification best handled through views
- Internal report customisation (SQL knowledge)
- Call Centre, Internal CRM, Company or customer asset tracking
- Web Interface – 3rd party or Internal Development
- Colour and Size attributes, 2D and 3D matrix (colour, size, style etc..)
- Sales / Cost reporting matrix
- Standard cost / average cost mix, Planning board, Constraint Scheduling
- Demand analysis and planning
- Multi-dimensional pricing modules, Manufacturing routing templates
- Flexible assembly inventory issues
- Reckon Accounts integration
- Export to Reckon, MYOB, Xero, Sage Pastel, MoneyWorks, Quickbook
- Customisable workflows per user
- Inventory management

Do you have any suggestions or recommendation?

Comment: Could you please detail the `Reckon, MYOB, Xero, Sage Pastel, MoneyWorks` part a bit? Thanks!

Comment: i meant it can export data to those applications. thank you for your response

Comment: same for Quickbook?

Comment: yeahh. that 's right ^^

Answer (score 2):

Should be Call-centre, CRM, workflows, multidimensional pricing, demand planning or constraint scheduling part of the system? Together they are shifting the scope to another dimension. I'm afraid you are not heading just towards a 'system', but towards an ERP implementation, maybe including customizations.

**Based on the above requirements, my answer is: nearly any well-established ERP can handle this**, just contact SAP, Oracle, Navision (etc.) vendors (at least 2-3 so you can compare the offers) and prepare relatively high amount of money.